# Writing Pandas data to CSV or SQL results in trailing 0 being dropped

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, csv

I have some data in a pandas data frame which is stored as follows:

0     NASDAQ   AAPL      1.63                  3.51              2.20
1     NASDAQ   AAPL    2.40                  3.59              1.74

When I export it either to a CSV file or an SQLite database, any number where the second decimal place is a zero is truncated to one decimal place (e.g. 2.40 becomes 2.4).

The code I'm using for the export is:

```
""" Export data to CSV file """

# Output final data as CSV
df.to_csv('stock_data-US.csv', sep=',', float_format='%.2f', encoding='utf-8', index=True)

# Connect to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()


""" Export dataframe to sqlite table """

# Export pandas array to sqlite table
df.to_sql("stock_data_US", conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Commit changes
conn.commit()

# Close database connection
conn.close()
```

As you can see I've specified the float format, however this seems to be being ignored (as decimal places are being rounded up). Ideally, I'd like all numbers exported to remain consistent at 2 decimal places.

Thanks in advance for any support!

Comment: You should probably use a different example as 2.40 == 2.4! Does the 1.74 truncate to 1.7?

Comment: No, 1.74 stays as 1.74. 2.20 truncates to 2.2, which is what I don't want. What I'm thinking if I can't fix on the export, can I reinstate the zero when I import the csv back into Pandas?

Comment: Why does the dropped zeros matter? Is it for aesthetic reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The *df.to_csv* in your code will work perfectly for numbers which have two non-zero digits after decimal point. For any zero after decimal point, it will be dropped while writing.
You should not have any problem with that.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this in the pandas data frame.

I noticed when the values were stored in the pandas data frame as a float I have the trailing zero; so all good. When the series was converted to a string (so I could add a $ or %) then I lost the trialing zero.

I found I could avoid the conversion to a string by using the following commands and achieve the same outcome:

Add leading $ sign

df['ABC'] = df['ABC'].apply(lambda x: '${:,.2f}'.format(x))

Add trailing % sign

df['ABC'] = df['ABC'].apply(lambda x: '{:,.2f}%'.format(x))

Thanks to those who responded.